# How can i add badge on the border of a component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have got this mobile Figma design , I could not find a way how to add that badge on right top corner border  of the component in react native ?

[image]

Comment: use this code a example https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-nightingale-13px0s

Comment: and for the future, remember to present your code and what you have tried to achieve the output, It's much more better when I have something(code) to build up on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your components like this, where your card will be the parent View and your badge is the child View components:

```
<View style={{position: "relative}} >
    <View style={{position: "absolute", right: 0, top: 0}}></View>
</View>
```

This is the general pattern, and you should customize your styles to fit your desired Design.